# C avormat_open_input dvb card not works

Tags: c, ffmpeg, centos

For multicast input this code works

```
AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;

// Open video file
if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, "udp://239.20.10.101:6000", NULL, NULL)!=0)
{
    printf("error");
    return -1; // Couldn't open file
}
```

but i want to make this work for dvb card so this code works but shows nothing

```
char *dev_name = "/dev/dvb/adapter0/dvr0";

AVFormatContext *pFormatCtx = NULL;

// Open video file
if(avformat_open_input(&pFormatCtx, dev_name, NULL, NULL)!=0)
{
    printf("error");
    return -1; // Couldn't open file
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: You can't straight up open a DVB frontend without activating it and setting it up first with tuning data. Something I've not yet done. The alternative would be to use dvblast with channel data and read the multicast from there.